# ListViewItem.Selected - Event

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, listviewitem

I'm displaying incomplete datasets in a listview.
When an item gets selected (doubleclicked or highlighted + enterKey),
I want to open a form, that allows me to add the missing data.

I checked the doc-page of [ListViewItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listviewitem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and found that I should probably either use [.OnSelected()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listboxitem.onselected%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)-Method or [.Selected](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listboxitem.selected%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)-Event. However my IDE(#develop) offers neither of those, just a **property** called Selected Adding hte [System.Windows.Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)-Namespace didn't change anything, though some googling suggested otherwise.

My question is:
How can I get access to these Methods/Events or is there a workaround, i.e. a ListView-Event that offers similar functionality?

Comment: Why aren't you using Visual Studio then?

Comment: @MaxMommersteeg I doubt that makes a difference; so far I haven't noticed any (dis-)advantages of either over the other.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind,
I used the [ListView.ItemActivate-Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.listview.itemactivate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).